# Problem with different outcome with DCT transformation on image while converting C++ to C#

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, dct

I tried to write APP that would make DCT-2 transformation on image fragment and then transform back with inverse DCT-2. I have found code in c++/opencv that I tried to convert to C#, but somehow, I have different outcome at some point. Here is the code i tried to convert:

```
for (unsigned v = 0; v < BLOCK_SIZE; ++v)
{   
    for (unsigned u = 0; u < BLOCK_SIZE; ++u)
    {   
        const double cu = (u == 0) ? 1.0 / sqrt(2) : 1.0;
        const double cv = (v == 0) ? 1.0 / sqrt(2) : 1.0;
        double dctCoeff = 0;

        for (unsigned y = 0; y < BLOCK_SIZE; ++y)
        {   
            for (unsigned x = 0; x < BLOCK_SIZE; ++x)
            {   
                double uCosFactor = cos((double)(2 * x + 1) * M_PI * (double)u / (2 * (double) BLOCK_SIZE));
                double vCosFactor = cos((double)(2 * y + 1) * M_PI * (double)v / (2 * (double) BLOCK_SIZE));
                double pixel = (double)(lenaNoseGrey.at<unsigned char>(cv::Point(x,y)));
                dctCoeff += pixel * uCosFactor * vCosFactor;
            }
        }
        dctCoeff *= (2 / (double) BLOCK_SIZE) * cu * cv;
        lenaNoseDct.at<double>(cv::Point(u,v)) = dctCoeff;
    }
}
```

And here is mine:

```
for (int v = 0; v < BLOCK_SIZE; ++v)
{   
    for (int u = 0; u < BLOCK_SIZE; ++u)
    {   

        double cu = (u == 0) ? 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(2) : 1.0;
        double cv = (v == 0) ? 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(2) : 1.0;
        double dctCoeff = 0;
        double dctCoeffAlpha = 0;

        for (int y1 = 0; y1 < BLOCK_SIZE; ++y1)
        {   
            for (int x1 = 0; x1 < BLOCK_SIZE; ++x1)
            {   
                double uCosFactor = Math.Cos((2 * x1 + 1) * Math.PI * u / (2 * (double)BLOCK_SIZE));
                double vCosFactor = Math.Cos((2 * y1 + 1) * Math.PI * v / (2 * (double)BLOCK_SIZE));
                double pixel = (double)bitmapaWy1.GetPixel((x1 + 284), (y1 + 313)).R;
                double pixelalpha = (double)bitmapaWy1.GetPixel((x1 + 284), (y1 + 313)).A;
                dctCoeff += pixel * uCosFactor * vCosFactor;
                //dctCoeffAlpha += pixelalpha * uCosFactor * vCosFactor;
                dctCoeffAlpha = pixelalpha;

            }
        }
        dctCoeffAlpha *= (2 / (double)BLOCK_SIZE) * cu * cv;
        dctCoeff *= (2 / (double)BLOCK_SIZE) * cu * cv;
        macierz[u, v] = dctCoeff;

    }
}
```

I have different outcome in my matrix, but when i convert matrix from the C++ code above with my inverse code, it works well. 
Can you find what have I done wrong? One difference I can spot is with getpixel method, but it is performed on exact same grayscaled image and image fragment that C++ code was performed.

When i inverse my matrix to image again, I can see image, but it has lot of random pixels that are too white, or too black.

Comment: I can't tell you at first glance, but why don't you -- for troubleshooting purposes -- replace the call to the `lenaNoseGrey.at<>(...)` and `GetPixel` method with some (inline) test value, and output (or write down) all the intermediary variables (and other related intermediary results) from both your C++ and your C# program and compare the results. It should hopefully become more obvious where your C# program deviates from your C++ program. Shouldn't be too difficult...

Comment: what is `APP` ?

Comment: +1 for elgonzo.  Write the intermediate data from each algorithm to a separate file and then you can diff them to find out where you go wrong.

Comment: Also change u, v, y and y loop variables to be unsigned in your version.  You have ints.  The original version has unsigned ints.   Not that it matters for the loop counting, but you then use them in floating point calculations...

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved, the issue was too much code, actual code i posted works, problem was code I had after it, which was changing "dctcoeff" to byte and it was inside loop, so value of dct didnt reset to 0;

```
int BLOCK_SIZE = 16;
        double[,] macierz = new double[16, 16];

        for (int v = 0; v < BLOCK_SIZE; ++v)
        {
            for (int u = 0; u < BLOCK_SIZE; ++u)
            {

                 double cu = (u == 0) ? 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(2) : 1.0;
                double cv = (v == 0) ? 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(2) : 1.0;
                double dctCoeff = 0;


                for (int y1 = 0; y1 < BLOCK_SIZE; ++y1)
                {
                    for (int x1 = 0; x1 < BLOCK_SIZE; ++x1)
                    {
                        double uCosFactor = Math.Cos((2 * x1 + 1) * Math.PI * u / (2 * (double)BLOCK_SIZE));
                        double vCosFactor = Math.Cos((2 * y1 + 1) * Math.PI * v / (2 * (double)BLOCK_SIZE));
                        double pixel = bitmapaWy1.GetPixel((x1 + 284), (y1 + 313)).R;

                        dctCoeff += pixel * uCosFactor * vCosFactor;
                        //dctCoeffAlpha += pixelalpha * uCosFactor * vCosFactor;


                    }
                }

                dctCoeff *= (2 / (double)BLOCK_SIZE) * cu * cv;
                macierz[u, v] = dctCoeff;

            }
        }
```

This code works like a charm. I hope some good soul will use it, becouse i spent about 20h into making it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a precision issue.

Most likely the problem is at the following line:

```
 macierz[u, v] = dctCoeff;
```

I also have doubt in:

```
            double pixel = (double)bitmapaWy1.GetPixel((x1 + 284), (y1 + 313)).R;
            double pixelalpha = (double)bitmapaWy1.GetPixel((x1 + 284), (y1 + 313)).A;
            dctCoeff += pixel * uCosFactor * vCosFactor;
            //dctCoeffAlpha += pixelalpha * uCosFactor * vCosFactor;
            dctCoeffAlpha = pixelalpha;
```